# Date column's format changing in pandas -python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe `df` with `Date` column:

```
Date
--------
Wed 23 Dec
Sat 28 Nov
Thu 26 Nov
Sun 22 Nov
Tue 1 Dec
Wed 2 Dec
```

The `Date` column is `object-type`, I want to change the format using `format="%m-%d-%Y"` into `yyyy-dd-mm`

**Expected output** `df`:

```
Date
---------
2020-23-12
2020-28-11
2020-26-11
2020-22-11
2020-01-12
2020-02-12
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format specified original data with added year, get column filled by datetimes:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+'2020', format="%a %d %b%Y")
print (df)
        Date
0 2020-12-23
1 2020-11-28
2 2020-11-26
3 2020-11-22
4 2020-12-01
5 2020-12-02
```

If need custom format add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), but datetimes are lost, get strings:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+'2020', format="%a %d %b%Y").dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
print (df)
         Date
0  2020-23-12
1  2020-28-11
2  2020-26-11
3  2020-22-11
4  2020-01-12
5  2020-02-12
```